# stacked url when using jquery ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

[image]

i want to use ajax to send post data to views,i'm tryin to implement pagination,when i click page button and send jquery.Post() data.
But the url got stacked what should i do?

.html

```
<div class="clearfix ">
    <ul class="pagination pagination-sm m-0 float-right" id="submits" >
      <li class="page-item" id="1" ><a class="page-link"  href="{% url 'postNewRA2' RAid 1 %}" id="1">1</a></li>
     
      
    </ul>
  </div>
```

.scripts
$(document).ready(function () {

```
    $('#submits li').click(function () {
        var a = $(this).attr('id');
        
        linkUrl = 'library/postNewRA2/71/' + a + ''
        alert(linkUrl);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: linkUrl,
            data: {
                'pages': 'panji',
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
            },
            dataType: "json",
            contentType : "application/json",
            success: function (result) {
                window.console.log('Successful');
            },
            error: function () {
                window.console.log('Error!');
            }

        });
    });
});
```

I expected the urlS just
http://127.0.0.1:8000/library/postNewRA2/71/1

Comment: Start the url with a _leading slash_: `'/library/postNewRA2/71/'`

Comment: As said on the first comment, you need the leading slash to refer to the root url, or add `window.location.origin` to have an absolute url

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat its solved thank you